# Save Mono to two repostiroy

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-webflux

Can you help me

What is the correct way to work with Mono in order to convert it into two different documents and save it to two different repositories?

```
  public Mono<OrderDto> makePayment(String orderId, PaymentPayPalRequest request) {
    return orderRepository.findById(new ObjectId(orderId))
        .doOnNext(order -> {
          var response = paymentPayPalService.makePayment(request);
          order.setStatus(response.getStatus());
          order.setPayments(Map.of(PaymentSystem.PAYPAL, response.getPaymentId()));
        })
        .flatMap(orderRepository::save)
        .map("HERE I want transform "response" to mongo document  and save to another repository")
        .map(orderConverter::convertDocument);
  }
```

**UPD1**

I rewrite my code. Is it good in terms of WebFlux?

```
  public Mono<OrderDto> makePayment(String orderId, PaymentPayPalRequest request) {
    return Mono.just(paymentPayPalService.makePayment(request))
        .flatMap(response -> saveToPayPalPayment(response).then(saveToOrder(orderId, response)))
        .map(orderConverter::convertDocument);
  }

  private Mono<Order> saveToOrder(String orderId, PaymentPayPalResponse response) {
    return orderRepository.findById(new ObjectId(orderId))
        .doOnNext(order -> {
          order.setStatus(response.getStatus());
          order.setPayments(Map.of(PaymentSystem.PAYPAL, response.getPaymentId()));
        })
        .flatMap(orderRepository::save);
  }

  private Mono<PayPalPayment> saveToPayPalPayment(PaymentPayPalResponse response) {
    var payPalPayment = payPalTransactionConverter.convertPayPalPaymentToDocument(response);
    return payPalTransactionRepository.save(payPalPayment);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several potential issues with the updated code

1. Wrapping non-reactive code

- use `Mono.fromCallable` instead of `Mono.just` that handles exceptions transforming them into `Mono.error`
- consider running blocking (non-reactive) code on a separate scheduler (e.g. `boundedElastic`)

```
return Mono.fromCallable(() -> paymentPayPalService.makePayment(request))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
```

2. Use `map` instead of `doOnNext`. `doOn...` are so called side-effect operators that typically used for logging or telemetry.

```
return orderRepository.findById(new ObjectId(orderId))
        .map(order -> {
            order.setStatus(response.getStatus());
            order.setPayments(Map.of(PaymentSystem.PAYPAL, response.getPaymentId()));
            return order;
        })
```